# Symfony2 / Form - This value is not valid

Tags: forms, symfony, relationship

I have OneToMany relationship(category and subcategory), all works fine, but now I try to generate choice from subcategory table when I know category ID, and set data to another table.

I have FormType and inside this:

```
$category = $options['categoryId'];
...
 ->add('subcategory', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'DbBundle\Entity\Subcategory',
                'query_builder' => function (SubcategoryRepository $repository) use($category)
                {
                    return $repository->getSubcategoriesByCategoryId($category);
                },
                'property' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'Select category',
                'empty_data' => null,
                'required' => false
            ))
...
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'categoryId' => null,
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
            'intention' => 'task_item',
        ));
    }
```

SubcategoryRepository:

```
public function getSubcategoriesByCategoryId($categoryId)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->select('s')
            ->join('s.category', 'c')
            ->where('s.category = :url')
            ->setParameter('url', $categoryId);

        return $qb;
    }
```

Category Entity:

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="icon", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $icon;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Subcategory", mappedBy="category")
     **/
    private $subcategories;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->subcategories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Add subcategories
     *
     * @param \DbBundle\Entity\Subcategory $subcategories
     * @return Category
     */
    public function addSubcategory(Subcategory $subcategories)
    {
        $this->subcategories[] = $subcategories;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove subcategories
     *
     * @param \DbBundle\Entity\Subcategory $subcategories
     */
    public function removeSubcategory(Subcategory $subcategories)
    {
        $this->subcategories->removeElement($subcategories);
    }

    /**
     * Get subcategories
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getSubcategories()
    {
        return $this->subcategories;
    }

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set icon
     *
     * @param string $icon
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setIcon($icon)
    {
        $this->icon = $icon;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get icon
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getIcon()
    {
        return $this->icon;
    }
}
```

Subcategory Entity:

```
class Subcategory
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="subcategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getCategory();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Subcategory
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \DbBundle\Entity\Category $category
     * @return Subcategory
     */
    public function setCategory(Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \DbBundle\Entity\Category 
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @return Subcategory
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }
}
```

If I load page, I see choice field with data, looks like all works perfectly fine, but If I submit form, I have error: **This value is not valid**

How could I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove this rules:

```
'property' => 'name',
'choice_value' => 'name',
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, now I have error: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DbBundle\Entity\Subcategory could not be converted to string

Comment: So my answer was correct ☺ Add a __toString method to yor Subcategory entity

Comment: I did, but now I have this error: Error: Method DbBundle\Entity\Subcategory::__toString() must not throw an exception

Comment: Try return  $this->name;